# Command works locally but failed on remote

Tags: centos, ssh, rhel, pdsh

I don't understand why my command fails when I use it remotely with ssh or pdsh :

Locally it works:

```
line=` last -F | grep -vE '^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)' | head -1 `;login=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`dm;user=`getent passwd $login` ;echo $line ; echo $user
```

But on remote it fails:

```
ssh User@Server " line=`last -F | grep -vE '^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)' | head -1 `;login=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`dm;user=`getent passwd $login` ;echo $line ; echo $user  "
```

I also tried it with pdsh :

```
/opt/techunix/bin/pdsh.sh -f /tmp/vmod/servers -c "line=`last -F | grep -vE '^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)' | head -1 `;login=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`dm;user=`getent passwd $login` ;echo $line ; echo $user"
```

Comment: you know that backquote are executed localy ?

Comment: Yes i know but i dont think that the error came from the backquote because i had used single quote at the first and the end of the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to escape characters that you don't want your local shell to interpret, namely "**`**" and "**$**"

Instead of:

```
ssh User@Server " line=`last -F | grep -vE '^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)' | head -1 `;login=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`dm;user=`getent passwd $login` ;echo $line ; echo $user  "
```

Do:

```
ssh User@Server " line=\`last -F | grep -vE '^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)' | head -1 \`;login=\`echo \$line | awk '{print $1}'\`dm;user=\`getent passwd \$login\` ;echo \$line ; echo \$user  "
```

You can also choose to put single quotes around the whole ssh command. Then, you need to only change the single quotes of the `awk` and `grep` command into double quotes:

```
ssh User@Server ' line=`last -F | grep -vE "^(svc_qual|s594998a|reboot|s823850a|s825722a|s559857a|s603256a|root|s823656a|s230281a|s638181a|s835786a)" | head -1 `;login=`echo $line | awk "{print $1}"`dm;user=`getent passwd $login` ;echo $line ; echo $user  '
```